# Absolute HTML element not showing until manually changing z-index in web inspector

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

I have a modal view that appears with the help of `-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);`

The problem is that absolute buttons inside this modal view are sometimes hidden.
But if I resize the window or change the z-index manually in the web inspector the buttons re-appears.

It's something to do with absolute positioning, z-index, images and webkit-transform. I tried to reproduce it in a js fiddle with no luck: http://jsfiddle.net/Hx5Es/1/

You can see the problem (only in chrome / safari) going here:

http://arjowiggins.logins.fr/arjowiggins/trunk/#/sync

Clicking on start and when it's done (2secondes) go here:

http://arjowiggins.logins.fr/arjowiggins/trunk/#/products

And there if you click on any image the button to close the modal view will not show at random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the overflow to hidden here:

```
<div swipe="" zoom="true" on-dezoom-close="closeFullScreen" items="products" callback="swiped" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;overflow:hidden"></pre>
```

It's probably generated by a third-party script your using, but it's causing the issue.

Comment: Yep the `overflow:hidden;` is causing the issue. Now I need to know why. I will investigate on that later, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that happened in Chrome v49. After tons of redraw/repaint functions, and css fiddling the one line that worked was `backface-visibility: visible;` on the **parent** element. I tried doing it on the element itself but no dice.

Also of note: The entire element and its parent was dynamically generated with mustache and inserted with jQuery. I was using a transform animation on entry, so all of this put together probably exposed a bug in Chrome.